# Conectar en red mysql workbench desde Windows Form c#

Tags: mysql, c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio hecha con Windows Form c# y mysql workbench. Lo que yo quiero es tener la aplicación conectada en la red local. O sea poner una IP Estática a la computadora donde va a estar instalado el servidor mysql y poder acceder de las demás computadoras desde la red local. Este es el string de conexión que tengo actualmente y me funciona bien:

```
//Con este String de conección Si me permite ingresar
    string connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=consulDesk;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;";
```

Ahora cuando yo le pongo la IP estática del servidor (a la computadora donde va a estar instalado el servidor que es la misma computadora donde uso el localhost) no me deja conectarme este es el código que probé:

```
string connectionString = @"Server= 192.168.1.156;Database=consulDesk;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;";
```

Este es el error que me tira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  //Con este String de conección Si me permite ingresar
    string connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=consulDesk;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;";
    
    //Con este String de conección No me permite ingresar
    string connectionString = @"Server=192.168.1.156;Database=consulDesk;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;";
```

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes dar acceso en el servidor para permitir conexiones, además de configurar el servidor para que acepte conexiones remotas.

intenta esto:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON consulDesk.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.156'
IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo! Lo solucione creando una cuenta con esa ip (192.168.1.156) desde mysql workbench y asignándole privilegios. Te agradezco la ayuda que me brindaste!